# create a button aligned on the left side of the page similar to next button in new google sign in page

Tags: html

I want to create a button aligned on the right side of the page similar to the "next" button in the new google sign in page with blue background. what is the code for that?

Comment: did you want to align button on the right side of the page or same as like google?? Please clearify.

Comment: Same as like google. I think google next button is aligned in the right.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.nextButton {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  border: 1px solid #4285f4;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="nextButton">
Next
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/b6mef2zu/1/)

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
a
{
  margin-top: 200px;
  float: right;  
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">next</a>
</div>
```